# What do I need to do to vertically align my image to the div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to align my image in the div. I tried some researching but I just couldn't understand why it is not compatible with the "thumbnail" class in bootstrap library:

Here is the **DEMO:** 
http://jsbin.com/yohuwitoguca/1/edit

I can't seem to make the img vertically aligned.

Comment: Please post code here instead of on another site. If that other site changes, the question will no longer make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your `.div-thumbnail` style:

```
display: table-cell;
```

http://jsbin.com/fidonoworile/1/edit